# Does my logo look like a Worry Stone?

Tags: logo, critique

[image]

The concept of the app logo is a physical worry stone that the user can interact with, the information is then logged into the app to help monitor and give advice for when the user may be feeling anxious. Above I have created a test logo, with many different colour variants. The background colour is what I will be mainly using inside the actual app, so to put it against the logo will help in deciding which colours fit best. I have tried to go for the pastel colours to help in reinforcing that the symbol resembles a worry stone.

If I was able to receive some feedback on whether this logo resembles the product, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an egg to me... but that is just me seeing this out of context with my zero knowledge of what the fudge a worry stone is...

Comment: From the contrast ratio aspect I would pick the top right or the bottom right variant, you can check [contrast ratio tool](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/) to find out how to archive a better contrast ratio.

Comment: What is a 'worry stone'?

Comment: Worry stones are smoothed stones that are designed for relaxation and anxiety relief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed moonstones has this indentation. So I followed closely as much as I can.

- First row - simple and minimal.
- Second row - slightly oval, looks more like a pebble/stone.
- Third row - odd-shaped, represents something natural.

Hope I've given you some inspiration :)

[image: Some concepts]

Answer (score 4):

I get the "material design" aspect.. but to me.. it looks like a mockup with something missing.

I think if you want "stone" you are going to *have* to use at least *some* skeuomorphism. Even Google breaks their material design guidelines when it's more appropriate to do so.

Comment: I agree. I think a solution is to add the small indentation on the front of the stone to make it look more like the worry stone.

Comment: I thought this myself. The issue is that I am fairly new to illustrator so I am still trying to figure out how to do it. Thank you for the advice though I will work upon it.